# Deleting Row in Dataframe and renaming columns

Tags: python, dataframe, delete-row

I am trying to delete the first row of the below dataframe and column 0 so that the first row, column 0 begins with 'Stats' and column 1 is then headed with 'Team Basic'.

[image]

However all of my code has resulted in the removal of the 2nd row. For example, the below code keeps the row with the random '14' in it...

```
away_basic_teamtotals_df = away_basic_teamtotals_df[1:-1]
```

[image]

How do I get rid of that first row with the '14' in it?

Answer (score 0):

I made the dataframe data as follows:

```
     0    1    2
0  NaN  NaN   14
1  aaa  bbb  ccc
2    a    1    0
3    b    2    0
4    c    3    0
5    d    4    0
6    e    5    0
7    f    6    0
```

Applied **away_basic_teamtotals_df.index != 1** masking, which returned True for all rows except the row with index 1.

```
print(away_basic_teamtotals_df[away_basic_teamtotals_df.index != 1])
```

Output

```
     0    1   2
0  NaN  NaN  14
2    a    1   0
3    b    2   0
4    c    3   0
5    d    4   0
6    e    5   0
7    f    6   0
```